# Spliterators parallel infinite loop

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

I've an iterator and I would use a parallel stream to process each entry of my set. So I've wrote this piece of code

```
int sum = StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(rowIterator, Spliterator.ORDERED), true)
                    .map(row -> insertDataFromExcel(row, user))
                    .mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
```

So, every entry is processed by my method and this return 1 if entry is stored on DB or 0 if any exception occurred during process. In the end I sum every int to get number of element correctly processed and stored.

`insertDataFromExcel` process each row of an excel file, opened with `Workbook` of `org.apache.poi` package. All parsing phases works fine, trouble occurs when I try to save this entity into my DB: before persist entity I find a possible duplicate of this on my DB trough a simple query. This query is performed with `JpaRepository`.

With code above my method was executed correctly but after execution I'm into a infinite loop and I can't get the int value, more execution is locked at this point of code and not proceed.

If I remove parallelism form `Spliterators` all works fine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please make a [mcve].

Comment: @Tunaki what's wrong in my question? There is problem, code, a possible workaround and a request

Comment: The example is far from being complete. What is `rowIterator`? What is `insertDataFromExcel`? Please refer to the link above. And it also needs to be minimal.

Comment: By the way, you don’t need another `.parallel()` call, if you passed `true` to `StreamSupport.stream`…

Comment: @Holger thanks for your replay, but I've tried to remove `.parellel()` and set only `true` to `StreamSupport.stream` but I've the same problem.

Comment: Of course, that’s what I said, you don’t need to specify `.parallel()`, if you already passed `true` to the factory method, as the Stream is already parallel then, with all consequences. As Tunaki already told, we can’t dig further without more details. But it looks very much like your method `insertDataFromExcel` is not thread safe.

Comment: @Holger I've update my question

Comment: Well, if a method isn’t thread safe, you can’t use it in a parallel stream. Well, you could guard its execution, but that would render the parallel stream useless, so staying sequential is easier *and* more efficient. If you want to know whether the method is thread safe or how to make it thread safe, it’s an entirely different question, unrelated to streams or lambda expressions. And an answer without seeing *the code* of the method is impossible anyway.